# How to make vertical scroll bar align with a specific <div id="target"> smoothly with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, animation, scrollbar

```
<body>
...
<div id="target"></div>
...
<a>click me</a>
</body>
```

When user clicks,make the vertical srollbar align with `<div id="targe">` smoothly

**EDIT**

Is it doable without other plugins?

Comment: But you have all this space in the body of the question that you're missing out on. It's such a **shame** to jam everything into the title of the question.

Comment: It's a little better. Keep trying ;-D

Answer (score 0):

try [smooth anchors plugin](http://www.ooeygui.net/articles/399)

**EDIT:**
It seems the previous jQuery plugin is not online anymore.

basically what you need is two things:

1. Create an anchor link
2. Use javascript for smoothing the transition

---

The basic idea is to prevent default click action and animate scroll:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

I can qoute the solution mentioned here as a more generic solution:
[Smooth Scrolling: Performs a smooth page scroll to an anchor on the same page using jQuery](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
  return string
    .replace(/^\//,'')
    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
    .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
  var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
    if (  locationPath == thisPath
    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
      if (target) {
        var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
        $(this).click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
            location.hash = target;
          });
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // use the first element that is "scrollable"
  function scrollableElement(els) {
    for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
      var el = arguments[i],
          $scrollElement = $(el);
      if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
        return el;
      } else {
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
        var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
        $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
        if (isScrollable) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    }
    return [];
  }

});
```

[Here is a more comperhensive explanation](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links)

Answer (score 0):

You will get that smooth scrolling effect from

[Animated Scrolling for Same-Page Links](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/animated-scrolling-for-same-page-links#header)

Comment: I just noticed that you pointed out the same solution I'm suggesting :)